# How to create a partition without Windows assigning a drive letter?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I am trying to initialize and partition an attached virtual hard disk through the Windows API. I have been successful using [DeviceIoControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do so, however whenever I apply the desired drive layout Windows is automatically assigning a drive letter to the partition and popping up an annoying "Would you like to format?" dialog.

My intent is to handle the formatting and mounting of this partition later in the program, but I'm not sure how to stop this behavior. I have tried setting `RecognizedPartition` to FALSE, but this seems to have no effect.

Relevant code:

```
Layout.PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
Layout.PartitionCount = 4;
Layout.Mbr.Signature = MY_DISK_MBR_SIGNATURE;
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].PartitionStyle = PARTITION_STYLE_MBR;
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].PartitionNumber = 1;
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].StartingOffset.QuadPart = MY_DISK_OFFSET;
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].PartitionLength.QuadPart =
   (Geom.DiskSize.QuadPart - MY_DISK_OFFSET);
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].Mbr.PartitionType = PARTITION_IFS;
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].Mbr.BootIndicator = FALSE;
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].Mbr.RecognizedPartition = FALSE;
Layout.PartitionEntry[0].Mbr.HiddenSectors =
   (MY_DISK_OFFSET / Geom.Geometry.BytesPerSector);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Layout.PartitionEntry[i].RewritePartition = TRUE;
}

if (!DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX,
                     Layout, dwLayoutSz, NULL, 0, &dwReturn, NULL))
{
    // Handle error
}
DeviceIoControl(hDisk, IOCTL_DISK_UPDATE_PROPERTIES,
                NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwReturn, NULL);
```

What can I do to prevent automatic drive letter assignment?

Comment: I haven't tried it, specifically because have no disk to spare for trying. However, what about attempting to open the device (`hDisk`) exclusively and then doing your thing? After all the exclusive access should ensure that the mount manager shouldn't meddle with your affairs, no? (that'd be `dwShareMode == 0`) +1 of course for the question.

Comment: Checked it - doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way I could find to work around this issue was to stop the "Shell Hardware Detection" service while the volume was created and formatted. However, this approach is so unapologetically silly that I refused to put it into code.

Another "hackish" option is to have the service start up and then immediately spawn itself (or a "worker" executable) in a hidden window via `CreateProcess()` with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag.

Since this software runs as a system service and I'd rather not complicate the code for something that only happens once or twice over the lifetime of the system, I've just had to accept that sometimes there will occasionally be an *Interactive Services Detection* window pop up for a few moments while creating the partitions.

If anyone discovers a good method for preventing the format prompt while programmatically creating and formatting a drive, I'll happily change the accepted answer (and owe you a beer).

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've used this API, but from memory you can't.  But it's doesn't stop you from [removing the drive letter assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after the fact.

I'm not sure if it will stop the format prompt tho, all the times that I have done this the partition has already been formatted correctly before I do the disk layout update.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem, by waiting for several seconds for the drive to be available and then directly issue a format action. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257643/after-partition-was-created-using-ioctl-disk-set-drive-layout-how-do-i-create-n).

Answer (score 0):

[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) has an interesting workaround: it installs a window event hook that detects the "do you want to format this drive?" prompts and immediately closes them. [See source code here](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/c5f4e5a2eed072ae569faf44ab5ee1c475abd4b4/src/stdlg.c#L1911-L1991).

It then goes on to arrange to mount only the partitions it cares about, but that's orthogonal.