# Initialize and partition disk - how to prevent "you need to format disk" message from appearing?

Tags: .net, windows, format, partitioning

I'm trying to initialize, partition and format a disk from application. OS is Windows Server 2008 R2. It doesn't really matter which method do I use for these tasks, but let's assume I'm using DeviceIoControl API.

As soon as application initializes and creates a partition Windows would pop a message box saying "You need to format disk...

[image]"

So, even though my application immediately formats this disk, message box would still be there, and user would be confused, and can actually format it again.

Is there way to prevent Windows from popping that message box?

Comment: I suspect that FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME (applied to the disk) will do the trick.  See the sample code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15013624/886887

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it appeared situation was a bit more complicated then I though originally. Let me explain my finding here, may be it will be useful for somebody else.

It really does matter which way you're initializing and formatting drive. For example the following **diskpart** script will do everything and Windows **WILL NOT** pop that message up:

```
select disk 2
create partition primary
select part 1
format fs=ntfs label="NEW DISK" quick
assign letter Z
exit
```

If you however try to assign letter first, and then perform format - message will appear.

But in my case I didn't want to have dependency on diskpart. I used **DeviceIoControl** API to initialize and partition disk and then was waiting for WMI to recognize the volume, so I can format it via WMI.

And unfortunately locking device wasn't an option too. Because if I do that, WMI won't recognize the volume.

Based on this answer [How to create a partition without Windows assigning a drive letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457254/how-to-create-a-partition-without-windows-assigning-a-drive-letter/11867015#11867015) I decided to go with stopping and starting **ShellHWDetection** service and it actually worked out perfectly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use DeviceIoControl for the first two steps but not to format the volume?

Comment: There was no way to initialize and partition the disk using WMI. So I had to go with DeviceIoControl. I could not find an easy way to format the volume using DeviceIoControl, and WMI seems to be easy approach.

Comment: You're quite right, there doesn't seem to be a control code to format a volume.  Rats.  The interesting question, I guess, is what diskpart does differently when creating the partition in order to prevent the shell from detecting the volume until a drive letter is assigned.

Comment: diskpart somehow automatically gets volume after partition was created, and using DeviceIoControl I wasn't able to get this volume directly. I had to wait until it appears in WMI stack.

Comment: I think the "correct" solution is VDS, which now that I think about it is what diskpart uses.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I had a drive that is formatted in a non-standard way, and I wanted to stop this message from popping up. Based on your answer, I went into Disk Manager in Windows and removed the drive letter association there. That prevents the message when I mount the drive. Hope that helps someone else too..