# Is It Possible to Suppress Windows Notification After Assigning Drive Letter

Tags: c#, windows, process, notifications, disk

I have an unformatted hard disk, which through code I created a single partition, assigned a drive letter, and finally formatted the hard disk (as NTFS).

The code works fine, however Windows displays the following popup as well as displays a notification message after formatting and opening up a Windows Explorer to that drive. I would like to at a minimum not have the popup notification message.

[image: You need to format the disk before using it.]

Here is the code, just to give you an idea of what I am doing.

```
Process oProcess = new Process();
...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine($"SELECT DISK={disk}");
sb.AppendLine($"SELECT PARTITION {partition}");
sb.AppendLine($"ASSIGN LETTER={driveNext}");
sb.AppendLine($"EXIT");

// Write the script to a file.
String fileScript = Path.GetTempFileName();
fileScript = Path.ChangeExtension(fileScript, @"scr");
pathScript = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileScript);
File.WriteAllText(pathScript, sb.ToString());

// Set process start information.
ProcessStartInfo oProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = @"diskpart.exe",
    Arguments = $"/s {pathScript}",
    CreateNoWindow = true,

    // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection of the standard output.
    UseShellExecute = false,

    // Redirect standard input as well.  This stream is used asynchronously.
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
};

    // Start the process setting our event handler to asynchronously read the command standard output.
oProcess.StartInfo = oProcessStartInfo;
...
oProcess.Start();

...

// Wait for the process to complete.
oProcess.WaitForExit();
...
```

What I want is a silent user experience and not having windows and notifications flying at the user inclusive of the notification area in Windows 10. I am thinking maybe there is a registry change, which I can temporarily make during the operation to silence Windows. Maybe there is something else.

Is it possible to temporailly silence Windows and if so, how?

**`UPDATE 2`**

Smartis recommended [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211900/initialize-and-partition-disk-how-to-prevent-you-need-to-format-disk-message?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) as it is the same as this question. That user phrased the question nicely in that a user can actually do damage by responding to the format.

The accepted answer, namely to format the drive with `DiskPart.exe` and then assign the drive letter, is what I do now, see Update 1 below. This approach obviously works with Windows Server 2008R2, but it does not work on my copy of Windows 10 Professional X64. Yes, I spawn another process with CreateNoWindow set to true.

That user said that one answer would be to stop the Hardware Detection Service, but that that was not a solution that he would dignify placing in code. I agree. I hope that that is not the only way, so here we are again.

Thoughts?

**`UPDATE 1`**

I did not think to mention another small issue earlier, but based on Ben's comment and new research, I am now.

I originally wanted to format the disk inside the `DiskPart.exe` command, but that failed. The few sites, which I looked at, gave the following code:

```
sb.AppendLine($"SELECT DISK={disk}");
sb.AppendLine($"SELECT PARTITION {partition}");
sb.AppendLine($"ASSIGN LETTER={driveNext}");
sb.AppendLine($"FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL='{diskLabel}' QUICK");
sb.AppendLine($"EXIT")
```

I then did new research after Ben's comment and came up with [this article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-clean-and-format-storage-drive-using-diskpart-windows-10), which solved the earlier problem of formatting the disk and assigning the drive letter inside a single `DiskPart.exe` call.

Here is a working `DiskPart.exe` script to assign a drive letter and format the disk. For whatever it is worth, in this script, not shown, I also create the partition.

```
sb.AppendLine($"SELECT DISK={disk}");
sb.AppendLine($"SELECT PARTITION 1");
sb.AppendLine($"ACTIVE");
sb.AppendLine($"FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL='{diskLabel}' QUICK");
sb.AppendLine($"ASSIGN LETTER={driveNext}");
sb.AppendLine($"EXIT");
```

The problem originally was that I did not have the `ACTIVE` line and secondly that I put the `ASSIGN` line after the `FORMAT` line.

Sadly, I still see the message box and notification, though the notification in the Windows 10 notification area is a minor annoyance, maybe even desirable.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would format it before assigning the drive letter.

Comment: If you use WMI you can avoid running a separate diskpart.exe process.  `MSFT_Volume` has a [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830489(v=vs.85).aspx) method, and `MSFT_Partition` has [`AddAccessPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh830482(v=vs.85).aspx) to set the drive letter.

Comment: @BenVoigt Though the combined code, see my question update, still produces the message box shown above, I am thankful for you that you pushed me to do another search. What I did not realize before is that I was omitting the ACTIVE prior to the format and that the ASSIGN statement comes after the format. A small step forward.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger There is a existing Question about this topic. Can it help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211900/initialize-and-partition-disk-how-to-prevent-you-need-to-format-disk-message?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Smartis Thank you for pointing out the article. That other user phrased the topic nicely that a user can actually do damage by responding to the format box. Sadly, the accepted answer for Windows Server 2008R2 is to format the drive using DiskPart and then assign the drive letter. I do that now in the updated code, however still the same problem on Win10. Stopping the HW detection service makes my skin crawl, and use CreateNoWindow to true, I already do that.

Comment: I thought that the answer was to remove the ACTIVE statement from the DiskPart.exe script, as that was the only difference that I saw between the accepted answer on the other post and my revised script. Further testing showed that at least on Win10 Pro that I still saw the popup message box and other notifications. That is sad. I sincerely thought that ACTIVE was the culprit. Oh well.